# git push --mirror - internal server error

Tags: linux, git, github, version-control, github-api

I have created a git repo using (GIT API) and initiated it with  git init. (but no `git add` or `git commit` command) . when i try to use the `git push --mirror` , it gives `internal server error`.

I saw the following bug (100+ ref will give internal server error)

https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1253

even my repo got 500+ refs.

Do i need to use git add and git commit to push the repository to github with mirror command ?

when i do the git add and git commit on local repo, i can push the content.

I'm doing all those using the API, and is it possible to use git push --mirror without any git commit or git add commands?

When i go to the remote repo, i can see the GitHub quick setup page, asked to execute git add, commit etc...

my questions is how should i avoid that GitHub quick setup page,and push my contents to the remote repo without executing git add, or git commit ?

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If so, you can mark the answer.

Comment: I also have this issue. I was trying to mirror a repo from google to a private repo at github, and after I did a `git push --mirror`, the response was

`remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (46283/46283), done. remote: Internal Server Error Everything up-to-date`

Were you able to resolve it @Markus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what's your content.

If you have file and don't `add` them and don't `commit`, you have no content, as far as git is concerned.

You need to have at least a commit to push your repository, **otherwise you're pushing nothing**.